# Show that $f:X\rightarrow \mathbb{K}$ is continuous iff $N=\left\{x\in X; f(x)=0\right\}$ is closed.

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, vector-spaces, solution-verification

> Show that the linear mapping $f:X\rightarrow \mathbb{K}$, over a normed vector space $X$, it's continuous iff $N=\left\{x\in X; f(x)=0\right\}$ is a closed subset of $X$.

Proof

Let's suppose that $f$ is continuous and show that $N=\bar{N}$, that is $N$ is equal to it's closure.

Consider $\{x_n\}_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\subset N,$ such that $x_n \rightarrow a$. Then
$$f(a)=f(\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}x_n)\overset{*}{=}\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}f(x_n)\overset{**}{=}\lim_{x\rightarrow \infty}0 = 0.$$

($*$) $f$ is continuous ; ($**$) $x_n \in N, \forall n\in\mathbb{N}$. Since $f(a)=0$, then $a\in N$, therefore $N=\bar{N}$.

Now, let's suppose that $N$ is a closed subspace of $X$. If $x,y\in N$, then
$$\|f(x)-f(y)\|=0\leq \|x-y\|.$$
Therefor $f$ is Lipschitz in $N$, which implies that $f$ is uniformly continuos in $N$, so $f$ is continuous at $0$. Finally, the last conclusion implies that $f$ is continuous in $X$.

Note: I can't see where I should use the fact that $N$ is a closed subspace of $X$ to prove the second part of this exercise. I thought the best way was showing that $f$ is continuous at $0$, as it's equivalent to being continuous in $X$. Is that proof correct? Is there a better way to prove?

Comment: Your proof is not correct. How does $f$ being uniformly continuous on $N$ imply it is continuous at $0$? Also it should be $n \to \infty$ in the limits and not $x \to \infty$. Note that $N$ is the inverse image of $\{0\}$ under $f$, so if $f$ is continuous then $N$ is closed as the inverse image of a closed set under a continuous function.

Comment: What is the topology on $\mathbb{K}$? Is it Hausdorff? Is it perhaps the Zariski topology, so that all closed sets of $\mathbb{K}$ are finite?

Comment: @QuantumSpace So I just need to change $x \ rightarrow \ infty $ to $ n \ rightarrow \ infty $ and the first part is okay? About the second part, I think I misinterpreted the theorem and you're right.

Comment: @Mastrem I really don't know that.

Comment: @Mastrem I think it is a safe assumption that $\mathbb{K}$ has the usual topology :) We are dealing with classical functional analysis after all.

Comment: @QuantumSpace Oh, so $\mathbb{K}$ is a specific field, like $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: yes $\mathbb{K}\in \{\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{C}\}$

Comment: @QuantumSpace Ah, now I understand. I am used to writing $k$ or $K$ or $\mathbb{K}$ for an arbitrary field.

Answer (score 1):

The second part of your argument would apply to a non-continuous functional, so it cannot possibly be right.

The usual way to prove this is to show that if $f$ is not continuous then $N$ is not closed. This is trivial, because if $f$ is not continuous at $0$, there exists a sequence $\{x_n\}$ with $x_n\to0$ and $f(x_n)=1$. Now given any $y\in X$ you have that $y-f(y)\,x_n\in N$ and $y-f(y)\,x_n\to y$. That is, $N$ is dense in $X$.

Comment: You assume that $f$ is not continuous, but then use that $f$ is not continuous at $0$?

Comment: Yes. If $f$ is continuous at $0$, it is continuous everywhere.

Comment: Ah, I see. Just translate.